# How do I install gmate in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gedit, plugins, gtk3

I am trying to install gmate in ubuntu 12.04, I followed instructions from [here](https://github.com/gmate/gmate#ubuntu)

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-on-rails/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install gedit-gmate

The package successfully installed, But I can't see any of the plugins included in gmate in gedit plug-ins list . What In am missed? Is gmate not compatable with Gedit included in ubuntu  12.04?

Answer (score 1):

It is an API issue, GEDIT changed API So most of the gmate plugins are broken

[Source](https://github.com/gmate/gmate/issues/140)